google-cloud-transcoder job not starting immediately after user signup
We're using google-cloud-transcoder services 3 years now - without any troubles -> working smoothly.
The only issue we found:
If a user starts a transcoder job (triggered via gcloud  function) immediately after signup (with all necessary permissions granted) the job is not starting.
After logout/login transcoder jobs are starting as expected.
Is there a logical reason for this behaviour?

  const {TranscoderServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/video-transcoder').v1;
  const transcoderServiceClient = new TranscoderServiceClient();
  const jobname = await createJobFromConfig(projectId, location, inputUri, outputUri, jobconfig, preset);

  async function createJobFromConfig(projectId, location, inputUri, outputUri, jobconfig, preset) {
    const request = {
       parent: transcoderServiceClient.locationPath(projectId, location),
       job: {
        inputUri: inputUri,
        outputUri: outputUri,
        config: jobconfig
       }
    };
    // Run request
     const [response] = await transcoderServiceClient.createJob(request);
     return response.name;
  }


Hi @BusinessDundee, Is it displaying any error, Could you please check the logs and more elaborate the issue?

That's the thing. It doesn't display any error and there is no log entry. It just didn't start the job. Pls see the added details above.

As mentioned, this only appears immediately after signing up a new user. After logout and sign in or sign in at another device, it works as expected.

Hi @BusinessDundee, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
